# How to make holder.js work together with Sinatra

Tags: sinatra, holder.js

Holder.js needs a calling syntax of "/holder.js/200x300" which includes a slash. The slash before the size is not recognised by Sinatra routing and can only result in "Sinatra doesn’t know this ditty." page.
How to make holder.js and Sinatra work together?

Answer (score 1):

Use `data-src` attribute to avoid 404 errors:

```
<img data-src="holder.js/200x300" src="">
```

Comment: It is not 404 error. Sinatra routing captures the the slash before the sizes and tries to figure out how to do it, instead of passing it to the holder.js.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the standard public folder i think you need to add a slash like this

> "/holder.js/200x300"

Example Code: https://bitbucket.org/l33tname/holder.js-sinatra-example/src

Comment: The problem is the second slash which is just before the size.

Comment: I just try it and for me it work with out a problem sample code @ https://bitbucket.org/l33tname/holder.js-sinatra-example/src [the files you are interested in are IndexController.rb and views/index.erb] so you need to be specific what does not work